# How to Invoice BOM products in OpenERP 7.0?

Tags: openerp-7

I have the following configured as BOM in OpenERP.

**Product A:** Coke - 250 ml  (Unit Price - Rs.10)
**Product B:** Coke - 24 Can x 250ml (Unit Price - Rs.200)

BOM:Product B = 24 x Product A
BOM Type: Sets/Phantom

When I ordered a a PO for single quantity of **Product B** to a supplier and Invoice it based on Receptions (Invoice Control: based on Incoming Shipemnts); I see that the created draft Invoice is showing up the line items of  **Product A** with the Unit price of **Product B**.  This results in amount of Invoice to be Rs. 4,800 (24 x 200) instead of Rs.200 in total.

How to make the **Supplier Invoice** pick the Unit Price from Product A to make the Invoice amount calculate correctly ?

Comment: could you please attach screen shots to make qus more clear?